# spring rest post?

Tags: java, spring, rest, restful-url

```
@ModelAttribute("user")
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public User saveUser( @RequestBody User user ) throws IOException {
        logger.debug(user);
        return user;
}
```

requestbody will convert the json into bean(pojo), is there required to use annotation     @ModelAttribute("user") in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ModelAttribute is not required in this case. For more information on this subject, please see Keith Donald's blog: [Ajax Simplifications in Spring 3.0](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/)